# Docker compose is not working as expected outside of Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, terminal

I created a .NET projet with docker integration from Visual Studio.

But then after i tried running the docker-compose file that was generated from outside Visual Studio using a Terminal it seems to run but i cannot access the service. What am i missing?

The docker-compose.yaml:

[image]

If i run the docker compose from inside Visual studio it runs well:

[image]

The dockerfile is:

[image]

And the docker-compose.override.yaml:

[image]

To conclude, I can access the api on localhost8080/swagger/index.html when running from inside Visual studio.

But if i try to run from a terminal using `docker-compose run web`
it doesn't work. Am i missing something? Is it something related to Visual Studio projects?

Comment: do you run the docker-compose command from your own system on windows? or inside wsl or another system? I think the volume mounts are causing the issue

Comment: I tried running from the normal terminal of windows, typing "cmd" in the search bar. The application starts on the terminal, but if I try to access with the URL nothing is listening there. Is the override file not applied? In Visual studio it is.

Comment: But even in Port 80 ir 443 it doesn't work.

Comment: how about port 8080 and 8081? (since they're the ports docker would listen on your system and maps them to ports 80 and 443 of the container)

Comment: manually running `docker-compose up` doesn't apply the override files. you should add `-f <file>` to add other override files. [more info](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)

Comment: Yes it seems it doesn't apply. But on a big project I work I use the command ```docker-compose up - - build``` and it works fine. I guess the build flag applies the override file?