# Running .NET Containers Outside of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, containers

I'm trying to wrap my mind around a microservice architecture using Docker containers, specifically with .NET 6.

I'm using VS 2022 and I'm able to add docker-compose, run everything and it all spins up. I also see the container in Docker Desktop. So far, I have no issues. I'm able to access the API with the port that VS randomly assigned, or by the one that I defined in my .yml file.

My question though is why can I only access this container when I'm debugging in Visual Studio? If I kill the debugger, the container still shows running in Docker Desktop, but I can no longer access my API. I want to be able to access the API on a static port, whether debugging or not, as long as the container is running.

Am I missing something? Is there another step I need to take to make the container stand on its own?

[image: The container in Docker Desktop]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you're trying to access the program by using command

```
docker-compose up
```

But to do that you need to specify the '-f' flag. Visual studio allows for all overrides it creates, but this responsibility lies on you if you want to do that manually.

You can take a look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68322823/docker-compose-is-not-working-as-expected-outside-of-visual-studio) question and [docker compose docks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)